# What did Edward tell me?

Tags: fiz

I received the instructions from Edward on brewing Fiz, such as they were.  Unfortunately I can't remember the exact details of what he said, and now I'm stuck.

For example, I think he said to talk to someone about the albino bees?  But I don't remember who or where.

What did he tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep brewing. The missing ingredients will show up in events over time. If you'd like to check the 'recipe' such as it is, it does show up in your brewing list.